# error importing a model in different django app

Tags: python, django, importerror, python-import

wishhing you a happy and a productive year. I have the following django project.

```
geoedu/
├── geoedu
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── geoedu.sublime-project
├── geoedu.sublime-workspace
├── manage.py
├── school
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── student
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

(btw i love tree command). My school app has a class named School

```
class School(models.Model):
    #fields
```

and the student app has a model named Student which has a foreign key of schools. So in my school/models.py

```
from school.models import School

class Student(models.Model):
    #name and other personal data fields
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='school')
```

So a student belongs only to one school but a certain school can have many students. But when trying to execute the sqlall command to see if everything is working fine, i get an import error

```
./manage.py sqlall school
ImportError: cannot import name School
```

and

```
./manage.py sqlall student
ImportError: cannot import name School
```

If i comment out the foreign key field and the import everything works fine. Why isn't it seeing the import? All project folder was created from terminal using the django-admin command and the apps using the manage command from scratch.

The sublime project file is the following

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
           "follow_symlinks": true,
           "path": "."
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: What about changing your `ForeignKey`'s model to `'school.School'` (note, you can use strings as model names instead of actual model classes, too!).

Comment: It worked!!Thank you..I know you can use strings as model classes, but why didn't it work importing it?

Comment: Could be a loop in imports, could tell something more if you'd post your `school/models.py`.

Comment: Yes...I have a model in the school app that uses student as foreignkey and student app imports Student class...Don't like it. Maybe i need better implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you've got imports loop in your models structure. Using the model's name `"school.School"` for `ForeignKey` should fix this. Or you could rethink your models' design.